# XNA windows phone 7 how to load from Content?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

"
If you want to play along, you can create a Visual Studio project named NaiveTextMovement
and add the 14-point Segoe UI Mono font to the Content directory. The fields in the Game1
class are defined like so: "

how to add 14-point Segoe UI Mono font to the Content directory?
iv tried creating a folder in the solution and placing the font in it then i try to load it using Content.Load ... but it doesnt work. how is that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a content project, then create a font description file.  Reference the content project from your main XNA project.

In fact, a content project should already have been generated for you.

The font description file is an XML file.  Editing it will be self-explanatory once you open it, as it will be auto-generated and well-commented.

Comment: how to create a font description file?

Comment: The same way you create any other file.  If it's not an option, you're not in your content project.

Comment: and.. where is the Content directory?

Comment: On the right in Visual Studio there is the 'Solution Explorer', the content directory is there. But can I suggest that you try and familiarize yourself with both Visual Studio and C# before delving into XNA.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Windows Phone 7 game project, the template creates two different projects in your solution. One is the WindowsPhoneGame project and the other is the WindowsPhoneGameContent project.

The Game project is where you'll be adding all your code and the Content project is where you'll be adding all your game assets like sprites, textures and spritefonts.

You can see in the image below the two projects shown in the Solution Explorer (that's the pane in the upper right if you have the default configuration for Visual Studio).

[image]

The "Content" project is the one highlighted in the above image.

To add a SpriteFont, simple right click on the Content project and select "Add" and then "New Item" from the Add menu. This will open up the below dialog.

[image]

From the "Add New Item" dialog, simply select SpriteFont and give it the name you want. That will add a new SpriteFont object to your Content project and to your game.